# How to add an histogram to estimator's train() and eval() cycles

Tags: python, tensorflow, histogram

I'm using a `tf.contrib.estimator.DNNEstimator` and I'd like to add my custom histogram to it which would be calculated from the labels and predictions.

I've seen I can very easily add a scalar metric with `tf.contrib.estimator.add_metrics()` but I can't see how can I add a `tf.HistogramProto()` for example.

I managed to do it outside the estimator train() and evaluate() cycles, but not from the inside ( with hooks, or adding metrics etc..)

Anyone knows how to do it?